# Please give example of Rails/Devise/LDAP Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ldap

I am stuck using get_ldap_param authenticating against an eDir ldap server. I can authenticate but when I try to read attributes I get nothing.

```
def get_ldap_email
    self.email = Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.uid, "mail")
end

def get_ldap_category
   self.category = Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.uid, "category")
end
```

In my ndstrace.log

```
92659520 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.401] New cleartext connection 0xe4b26c0 from     192.168.21.40:58658, monitor = 0x4b37c940, index = 8
1256683840 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.401] DoBind on connection 0xe4b26c0
1256683840 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.401] Bind name:cn=admin,o=xxx, version:3, authentication:simple
1256683840 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.401] Sending operation result 0:"":"" to connection 0xe4b26c0
1310226752 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.402] DoSearch on connection 0xe4b26c0
1310226752 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.402] Search request:
base: "cn=ntr,ou=Meta,o=xxx"
scope:0  dereference:0  sizelimit:0  timelimit:0  attrsonly:0
filter: "(objectclass=*)"
no attributes
1310226752 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.402] Empty attribute list implies all user attributes
1310226752 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.403] Sending search result entry "cn=ntr,ou=Meta,o=xxx" to connection 0xe4b26c0
1310226752 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.403] Sending operation result 0:"":"" to connection 0xe4b26c0
1261947200 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.405] Monitor 0x4b37c940 found connection 0xe4b26c0 socket closed, err = -5871, 0 of 0 bytes read
1261947200 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.405] Monitor 0x4b37c940 initiating close for connection 0xe4b26c0
1251420480 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.405] Server closing connection 0xe4b26c0, socket error = -5871
1251420480 LDAP: [2011/11/14 10:10:07.405] Connection 0xe4b26c0 closed
```

The error I get after logging in:

```
NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController#create

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.each
Rails.root: /home/ntr/Dropbox/source/devise

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Request

Parameters:

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"nkuzPnh8MCK4rh/RXUErrAjVJB9ciy56hfavG60I8ck=",
 "user"=>{"uid"=>"ntr",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "remember_me"=>"0"},
 "commit"=>"Logga in"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None
```

I've been searching high and low for some kind of tutorials for this on the web but only found basic implementations of the devise_ldap addon. Non using get_ldap_param.

Would love to get some examples, tips etc.

//Roger

Answer (score 1):

The dstrace is showing that you are getting all the attributes returned:

`Empty attribute list implies all user attributes`

But it does not show the returned data in dstrace anymore.  Older eDirectory at one point did show the results in trace but not for a long time now.

So I would suggest eDir is sending the data back.  Now on to how your app is parsing that response.

Comment: I ain't doing any parsing in my app besides the get_ldap_param methods and I've added columns in an migration for email and category. I've also added the :email and :category to the attr_accessible in my user model.

Comment: As you said geoffc ... the question is what is ldap returning? And am I asking ldap the wrong question as it thinks it should return everything. I obviously got a mail attribute in my object, but my LDAP server says the query is empty?

Answer (score 1):

The problem, in part, is that currently, devise_ldap_authenticatable gem does not pass in an authentication password to this function.

https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/issues

I wish there was a callback where one could extra more out of the LDAP response from authentication, but that doesn't seem possible.