# Ruby on Rails 3: Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ldap

I am running:
Ruby 1.9.3p0,
Rails 3.1.1,
Devise 1.4.9,
Devise_ldap_authenticatable 0.4.10

I am using Devise to authenticate my Rails application via an ldap server. I am using username instead of email to authenticate, so naturally the email field in my table is blank.

To query the ldap for email, the official way is to add this code in the user model:

```
before_save :get_ldap_email
def get_ldap_email
  self.email = Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"mail")
end
```

This code fails, without attempting to do anything with the ldap, with this:

```
undefined method `mail' for nil:NilClass
```

It refers to the line inside the method definition. The log output is no more helpful:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 10.50.1.96 at 2011-11-15 11:18:16 -0800
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"<hidden>=", "user"=>{"username"=>"<hidden>", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = '<hidden>' LIMIT 1
  LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: uid=<hidden>
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: uid=<hidden>
  LDAP: Authorizing user <hidden>
  LDAP: LDAP dn lookup: uid=<hidden>
  LDAP: LDAP search for login: <hidden>
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 251ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `mail' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/user.rb:14:in `get_ldap_email'
```

All lines previous to the 500 error are normal LDAP successful authentication that are unrelated to the the email query.

I started learning Ruby, Rails, and Devise just last week, so I'm not sure what files would be the most telling, but here is my user.rb model and gemfile:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :ldap_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_save :get_ldap_email

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :username, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me

  def get_ldap_email
    self.email = Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.username,"mail")
  end
end
```

And the gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


<... unrelated ...>

gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem "devise"
gem "devise_ldap_authenticatable"
```

I have tried restarting the server, and have done a bundle install since the last GemFile update. My configuration has ldap_create_user = true and username is the correct field name in users. Is there an error in that method? Could there be a version incompatibility? I'm not really sure what else to check, and rails is giving me nothing beginner-friendly to go on. I would love some help with this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having this problem - my current temporary solution is to fetch the data myself using `Net::LDAP` instead of the `ldap_authenticatable` classes. The more permanent solution would, of course, be to patch `ldap_authenticatable`, which I may try to do next.

The issue (at least for me) was this: After poring through the `ldap_authenticatable` code (namely ldap_adapter.rb) I discovered that the `get_ldap_param` method is not authenticating with the server when trying to fetch the params unless `admin_user` and `admin_password` are specified in ldap.yml. So, if your LDAP server allows anonymous reading of data, then `get_ldap_param` will work as advertised. On OpenLDAP (which is what I use for local testing), anonymous read access is set with the "access to" property in slapd.conf:

```
access to *
  by anonymous auth
```

But, my corporate LDAP does not allow that.

The Net::LDAP instance in `ldap_authenticatable` needs to be created with auth parameters when being used for parameter fetching, but it's not. No auth parameters are given, so no results are returned.

So, temporarily, I have the following code in my User model, calling `get_ldap_data` as a before_save filter:

```
def has_ldap_data?
  [self.email, self.first_name, self.last_name].none? {|v| v.nil?}
end

def get_ldap_data
  return true if has_ldap_data? or self.password.nil?

  ldap = create_ldap
  ldap.search(
    :base => ldap.base,
    :attributes => ['cn', 'sn', 'givenname', 'mail'],
    :filter => Net::LDAP::Filter.eq('cn', self.username),
    :return_result => true) do |entry|
      self.email = entry.mail.first
      self.first_name = entry.givenname.first
      self.last_name = entry.sn.first
  end

  has_ldap_data?
end

def create_ldap(password = nil)
  ldap_config = ldap_config = YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(::Devise.ldap_config || "#{Rails.root}/config/ldap.yml")).result)[Rails.env]
  ldap_options = {
    :host => ldap_config["host"],
    :port => ldap_config["port"],
    :base => ldap_config["base"],
    :auth => {
      :method => :simple,
      :username => "cn=#{self.username},#{ldap_config['base']}",
      :password => password || self.password
    }
  }

  ldap_config["ssl"] = :simple_tls if ldap_config["ssl"] === true
  ldap_options[:encryption] = ldap_config["ssl"].to_sym if ldap_config["ssl"]

  Net::LDAP.new(ldap_options)
end
```

Modify per your particular needs. It's not ideal, but works for now until forking/patching `ldap_authenticatable` to account for this use case.

Answer (score 2):

So here's the problem and a potential solution.

`ldap_get_param` assumes that anonymous read access to the LDAP server is allowed, and thus tried to bind and read with `{:method => :anonymous}`.  If your server does *not* allow anonymous searches, and eg. Active Directory does not by default, then your call will fail with the obscure error message above, which is really trying to say "no matching results".

Unfortunately, `devise_ldap_authenticable` does not allow you to require authentication for read operations, so I went and forked a copy that does.  To use it instead, slot this into your Gemfile instead of the original:

```
gem 'devise_ldap_authenticatable', :git => 'https://github.com/jpatokal/devise_ldap_authenticatable.git'
```

And then call get_ldap_param like this:

```
Devise::LdapAdapter.get_ldap_param(self.login,"mail",self.password)
```

Note the 3rd parameter there.  I've also submitted this as a pull request to master, and you can track the issue here: https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable/issues/94

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't got the answer for you, but I can tell you that I'm getting the same exact error as you.

I've done a couple of posts here at StackOverflow but haven't gotten any answers. Everything works fine for me until I try to pull extra attributes and :before_save. I've traced my eDir server with ndstrace and it says the question it gets is empty?! So it seems that my selected attribute is not passed down to the ldap server.

Comment: Knowing that other people are getting this error is vastly comforting to me (not that I'm happy you're getting the error!) - I'm glad I'm not going totally crazy here. Thankfully it isn't a total show-stopper, but I'm very interested to see if an answer shows up on this one.

Comment: @RogerNordqvist Can you post your dstrace of the search that is not working?

Comment: @geoffc I got it in my own question about this subject over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8121552/please-give-example-of-rails-devise-ldap-deviseldapadapter-get-ldap-param-usag). Please check it out.

Comment: @RogerNordqvist Thanks, I ended up finding that otherwise and posted on that question.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is related to the version you are using.

Inspecting the git repository of the project, I see that the method `get_ldap_param` has been introduced with version 0.4.7.

Check that you have no constraints on the version of the `devise_ldap_authenticatable` gem in your Gemfile, and remove them in the case, then run

```
$ bundle update devise_ldap_authenticatable
```

it should update your gem to version 0.6.0 (with `devise` 2.0.1), and the method is present and working.

You could also specify a minimum version in the Gemfile, if you think it is the case:

```
gem 'devise_ldap_authenticatable', '~> 0.4.7'
```